# Get Max Heap Size of Running JVM from Command Line: No JDK Tools

Tags: java, bash

I am working on a bash script that performs operations on our Java application web server prior to the web server going down for a restart/reboot. As part of this, I need to find out what was the maximum heap allocation that was provided to the JVM (the Xmx option). This value of this option will vary, depending on the hardware where the web application was deployed. I am looking for something I could use in a script to populate a variable like:

```
XMX_JVM_VALUE=$(command[s] here)
```

I will then be using this value to determine if there is enough space on our logging partition to create a heap dump there. That value will be gathered via:

```
LOG_DISK_SPACE=$(df -P /var/log | awk 'NR==2{print $4}')
```

The two restrictions I have is that I cannot use JDK tools as there is only the JRE on the server and I am limited to regular Linux commands that came with the system (Things like `grep`, `ps`, `awk`, etc...).

Comment: Worst case would be parsing it out of `/proc/yourpid/cmdline`

Comment: I have been looking into doing something similar to this. The issue is is dealing with the potential prefixes appended to the Xmx option (`Xmx2048m`, `Xmx4g`, etc...) and transforming the results into just a number representing that value in straight bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, I came upon the following solution. It does use the assumption that the JVM process with the biggest `Xmx` value is the one of interest.

```
DATA_UNIT_MULTIPLIER=1024
XMX_JVM_VALUE=$(ps -ef | grep -oP "Xmx\d+(m|g)" | sort -rn | cut -d'x' -f2 | head -1)
XMX_DATA_UNIT="${XMX_JVM_VALUE:$((${#XMX_JVM_VALUE}-1)):1}"
XMX_JVM_NUM=$(echo $XMX_JVM_VALUE | sed '$s/.$//')

XMX_SIZE=1
if [ "$XMX_DATA_UNIT" = "m" ]; then
    XMX_SIZE=$(($XMX_JVM_NUM * $DATA_UNIT_MULTIPLIER ))
elif [ "$XMX_DATA_UNIT" = "g" ]; then
    XMX_SIZE=$(($XMX_JVM_NUM * $DATA_UNIT_MULTIPLIER * $DATA_UNIT_MULTIPLIER))
fi
```

This implementation converts the value of `Xmx` into the same units being reported by `df`. It also take into consideration the unit suffix on the `Xmx` option.

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal 2> /dev/null | grep MaxHeapSize
```

The `java` command is available in the JRE.

Comment: Realized that the problem with this is that it probably starts a new JVM and gives its statistics, not the JVM that you want to learn about.

Comment: It does look to be that way.